# c++ // Segmentation fault at 4d <vector>

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

so this is my first question at stackoverflow, but you guy already helped me a lot.

I create an 4d vector in my grid.h file

```
class Grid{

 public:


  Grid(Params *);
  ~Grid();

void Set_Cube();
void Add2Grid(SPH_Part *);
int getSize(int, int, int);

vector<vector<vector<vector<SPH_Part> > > > grid;
Params *param;
};
```

then I resize it to 100 X 100 X 100 in grid.cpp

```
void Grid::Set_Cube(){

    #define HEIGHT 2*param->Ref
    #define WIDTH 2*param->Ref
    #define DEPTH 2*param->Ref


    grid.resize(HEIGHT);
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
       grid[i].resize(WIDTH);

       for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j)
          grid[i][j].resize(DEPTH);
       }
    }
}
```

and fill up the 4th  dim with structs

```
void Grid::Add2Grid(SPH_Part *part){
    for (int j=0; j< param->Npart; ++j) {

    //.....code....//

        grid[part[j].cube[0]][part[j].cube[1]]part[j].cube[2]].push_back(part[j]); 
    }
```

...
here I still have access to the whole vector
...

```
     for (int i=0; i< 21; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j< 75; ++j) {
            for (int k=0; k< 36; ++k) {

                cout<< grid[i][j][k].size() << " " << i << " " << j << " " << k << endl;
            }
        }
    }    
return;
}
```

But if I make a call afterwards from somewhere in the code via the getter function ( it neither works with direct access) I get an segmentation fault.

```
int Grid::getSize(int i, int j, int k){
    cout << "grid " << i << " "<< j << " "<< k << " "<< endl;
    cout << "grid " << grid[i][j][k].size() << endl;
    return grid[i][j][k].size();
}
```

GDB gives me:

```
grid 20 74 35 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004032c8 in Grid::getSize(int, int, int) ()
(gdb)
```

The segmentation fault occurs on a (for me) random iteration.
I would be really happy if someone got an idea what could be the problem.

Comment: Probably unrelated typo: grid[part[j].cube[0]] [part[j].cube[1]] **[** part[j].cube[2]].push_back(part[j]); Have you considered switching to a 1D vector of vector of SPH_Part?

Comment: Why do you use 21, 75 and 36 in the code printing sizes when all dimensions are the same: `2*param->Ref` ?
BTW, you can try to build with `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` or replace `[x]` with `.at(x)`, it throws an exception when an index is out of a vector size.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: @ Bob_
-The missing bracket is indeed just a coping mistake.
-Isn’t an 3d vector just a vector of vectors ?

Comment: @ Red User
- 21, 75 and 36 was just a special case I tested (I forget while coping), but it runs over the whole vector.
-I replaced [x] with .at(x) and it's still just a segfault.

Comment: -I am not quite shure if I used _GLIBCXX_DEBUG the right way, but it gives me: 
    a.out: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Abgebrochen
What barely tells me nothing :S

Comment: Now we know that segfault is not connected with bad index in operator[]. It seems to me that the only dangerous operation in shown code is accessing to part in Grid::Add2Grid(SPH_Part *part).
Try to run under valgrind.

Comment: @Red User
Thanks for the tipp, valgrind looks like a great tool.
I probably screw up a pointer in a function before the one causing the segfault. Now I think I can track down the bug.